# Requests.get does not work, Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to a web-scraping. Firstly the code was working but later it does not. The code is

```
import requests
import hashlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def sha512(x):
    m = hashlib.sha512(x.encode())
    return m.hexdigest()

session = requests.Session()
session.cookies["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"

r = session.post("https://ringzer0ctf.com/login", data={"username":"myusername","password":"mypass"})
r = session.get("https://ringzeractf.com/challenges/13")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

It gives error like

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ringzeractf.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded 
with url: /challenges/13 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04228490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL in the GET request is wrong. Change `ringzeractf` to `ringzer0ctf`